# How avoid having /******/ in front of each line in Javascript/Node Bundles?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

*Update:*

I work in Node.js test project (using **WebPack**), where inside the development builds (app.js) in start of each line, there is

```
/******/
```

[image]

So, as it seems a common behavior, is there any well-known way to remove them? (in Production/minified version they don't exist. However, switching the mode to `production` is not an accepted solution for this problem).

---

extra info:
Just for your interest, here is reason why I want: it might not be a big deal, I know that they are only in development mode, however while the app.js is around `5 Mb` and having thousands of lines, those extra characters might end up in around 100kb, causing theoretical slowdown (say, XXX milliseconds ) of the loading of the app.js, and why we (developers) should loose i.e. on each page refresh?

Comment: What is building this? It's worth noting that once minified this goes away, and even if it didn't, compression will crunch this down to effectively nothing since it's just duplicated symbols.

Comment: Seems quite strange? What are you using for build?

Comment: Besides the fact that this bundling behaviour is strange, how would just a 100kb extra file size slowdown your app by 100-500ms?

Comment: Loading the page in localhost, regardless of the file size, is instant. Are you not using localhost in development mode?

Comment: @yqlim  there are two problems. with this specific project I ask, we use external service/site, not localhost. generally, even on localhost server, loading of files are not instant (unlike cached resources). they do take some MS.

Comment: Are you sure this does it for every line? In a Webpack application I'm working on I only see it for the Webpack preamble, a bit of common code at the start, about 87 lines or so. The rest is normal, barring some source origin hints, one per file. In other words, an additional **696 bytes**. This is not the end of the world. It makes my app 0.004% bigger than it would otherwise be.

Comment: @tadman I surely understand what you say, just I doubt you understand my point. firstly, it does add till the end of file in my case.  I think i shouldnt have mentioned the reason, it could have been better for everyone to avoid unnecessary discussions. however, please transform your comment into answer, i will upvote that as a reasonable answer.

Comment: I don't understand your point because I don't think you've approached this empirically, as in actually measured the cost of this. How much does the file shrink when you delete these comments? How much does this improve load times? All I see here is speculation which taken too far leads to unfounded paranoia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack has some quirks, and one of them is it prefaces its preamble with that 8-byte comment sequence, at least in development mode.

There are alternatives to Webpack like [Parcel](https://parceljs.org) that focus on performance, so if you're suffering from slow build times that's likely the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're using Webpack to bundle the dependencies in *development* mode. Change it to production mode, by running Webpack with `--mode=development` or by specifying `mode: 'development'` in your config file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know that `production` sorts out many things.  However, i dont want to switch to "production" to avoid just this problem.

Comment: In development mode this is all irrelevant. Those extra bytes won't be seen by your end users. Transferring 100KB locally takes zero time.

Comment: @tadman No, i surely know that, but it affects me/our developers, as browser/rendering/etc, might delay 100-500 ms, which is not perfect to loose on each page refresh. Just why we should need it, if we can remove.

Comment: If you're stressing about 100ms while using Webpack, which often takes 4-10 seconds to compile each time, I think you've got some mixed priorities.

Comment: @tadman, there is no "one time" process. there are 30-40 chunks generated, and then in the backgrounds, uploading of those chunk to servers.... each of them taking extra 100kbs , in sum might be something.  I understand that this is still less than build time itself, and quite insignificant, but I just asked, why should we loose even 1-2 seconds for nothing, if it's possible to get removed?

Comment: Why not look into the Webpack source? If you're really stressing about build times look at [Parcel](https://parceljs.org) as an alternative. It could save you exponentially more time.

Comment: @tadman this last comment too, you can move all your comments into answer, and i will vote for that, as reasonable answer. I didnt know about Parcel.